# podcast app that can play downloaded podcasts trasferred from PC

Tags: applications, itunes

I am new to Android, coming from iPhones.

I am after an app or a way that can allow me to play podcasts that I have already downloaded on my PC.

In itunes, I just drag and drop the podcast episodes into the iPhone and the Podcast app automatically sorts and displays them ready for playing.

All the ones I've tried for Android (i've tried about a dozen of the free ones), but none seem to offer this functionality.

They all offer to subscribe and download directly on my phone.

To sum up:
I just need to play the files transferred from a PC, not download them, as I manage all my music and podcast from a central PC.

I have tried just dragging the files inside separate folders into the phone, but they come up all jumbled in the music player app, though at least organised inside the folders.

Any suggestions on APPs (ideally free ones as all I really need is an organiser style APP, nothing fancy) or even tweaking existing Android apps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no specific solution like that for podcasts.

If you have them as media files, you can of course upload them to a device and play using any multimedia program like [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc). The downside is that you will have to organize them yourself.

However, I really encourage you to try a podcast app like [Podcast Addict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bambuna.podcastaddict). Most of these allow you to choose to stream or download the podcast, keep track of new episodes (you will get a notification on your device), search for new podcasts and much more :-)

In general, the biggest point-of-view change when coming from iOS will be the fact that your Android phone is much more autonomous than an iPhone :-) You are expected to do most stuff locally on the phone and it is most efficient that way :-)

Comment: thanks for the reply. good to know. the problem is i have a huge library of podcasts going back over 10 years and like to cherry pick a range of different ones to catch up on....and easier that one computer handles all my music and podcasts..... i suppose i can try to sort by date and then add a sequential number to the file name so that the music player displays them in the right order....any other suggestions for work arounds welcome...

Comment: The Podcast Addict app I mentioned has options to "Add folder content as virtual podcast" and "OPML import". You could try these :-) In the app just click the + in a circle and scroll down the tile list. Apart from that, Google Music has podcasts support and file upload capability, but I never tried uploading podcasts to it

Comment: OK, an update on this issue.   Podcast addict is indeed a great app! First of all, the "add folder content..." does work and it adds the content and displays everything nicely. Secondly, it has options to display the list in various ways, such as by publication date, length of podcast, etcetc. Thirdly, it has great options like sleep timers, etc.      The only problem, though a big one, is, for some reason it messes up the sort by publication order. I've checked this with quite a few BBC podcasts and is puzzling. Not critical, but for serial/news podcasts, it's very very annoying... Any ideas?

Comment: As I said, I never used this upload options, so unfortunately I can't help beyond advising you to check the timestamps of the files on your PC, maybe those can be manually changed.